# AndEngine GLES 1 SpritedDisappearing when attaching to another sprite

Tags: android, andengine

I am using AndEngine GLES1.  I have created 2 sprites one is called sphere and the other is called user_sphere.

In the beginning, both are simply attached to the scene.  When a certain condition arises, I want to attach the user_sphere as a child to the sphere.

Here is the code that runs to do it:

```
                    if(user_sphere_attached == false)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "------------DETACHING and RE-ATACHING USER SPHERE-----------");

                        // Make sure we only do this once
                        user_sphere_attached = true;

                        // Detach the user_sphere from the scene
                        user_sphere.detachSelf();

                        // Add the user_sphere as a child of the main sphere
                        user_sphere.setParent(sphere);

                        // Convert the the scene coordinates of the mini_sphere to the local coordinates of the sphere
                        float[] coordinates = { sphere.getX(), sphere.getY() };
                        float[] localCoordinates = sphere.convertSceneToLocalCoordinates(coordinates);

                        // Reposition and scale the user_sphere to see if it shows up
                        user_sphere.setPosition(localCoordinates[0]+80, localCoordinates[1]+80);
                        user_sphere.setScale(5.0f);
                    }
                }
```

However, when that block of code runs, the user_sphere simply disappears from the screen.

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!!